# Setting up Nextcloud on Raspi; cannot connect to custom domain

Tags: nextcloud

### My Goal:

I'm trying to setup my raspi to host a nextcloud server, and I've also purchased a domain name; let's say it's [www.johndoe.com](http://www.johndoe.com) . My goal is to be able to log in to this cloud from any machine at the url [www.johndoe.com/nextcloud](http://www.johndoe.com/nextcloud).

**Edit:** *Solution:* I hadn't set up port-forwarding for http for the domain johndoe.com within my router's config. Having done that now, the cloud hosting is working. Dumb mistake that isn't related to the raspi, Sorry everyone.

### My approach, and the problem:

The instructions I'm following [here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-nextcloud-server/) are great (alternative suggestions also welcome), however the problems start when I get to the section "Nextcloud Initial Setup", as I am not able to connect from other devices. To work around this and complete the initial setup, I worked from the raspi itself at the url `localhost/nextcloud`. That works fine. I've also got the raspi's IP address using `$hostname -I`, (let's say it's `123.456`). However I cannot connect via the domain.

To narrow things down:

- When I type in `123.456` into the browser of my laptop, I get the Apache2 Debian Default Page, which establishes that my raspi is connected to the network and able to host.
- When I type in `http://123.456/nextcloud/` on my laptop, I'm able to connect to the cloud on the raspi (provided I add `123.456` to the "trusted_domains" setting in config/config.php). This establishes that http connection from my laptop to the nextcloud instance on the raspi is also working.
- When I open a terminal on my laptop and type `$ssh [user]@johndoe.com` I'm able to connect headless to the raspi. This establishes that the domain name is properly forwarding to my raspi.

***However***, when I type `http://www.johndoe.com/nextcloud/` into that same laptop browser, I get "Unable to connect" (even with johndoe.com included in "trusted_domains")

#### My best guess:

My first doubts were at the point where I had to choose between "**Running Under a Directory**" and "**Running NextCloud on its own domain**" (which determines what one should use for the `nextcloud.conf` file). The choice seems unclear to me, because johndoe.com *is* the domain for the raspi. Can someone clarify which version of the nextcloud.conf file I want?

Any suggestions or observations would be much appreciated (also please let me know if I'm posting this in the wrong place).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Are you trying to connect to `http://johndoe.com/nextcloud` from the same computer where you can use `ssh user@johndoe.com`. Use a network sniffer like Wireshark or tcpdump to see what exactly happens when you try to connect using your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the laptop where I ssh into my raspi at johndoe.com is the same machine from which I cannot access the http link.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I wasn't forwarding all the necessary ports to the raspi. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add port-forwarding for http. Everything works now.